# Using pygames Collision module without initializing display

Tags: python, opengl, pygame

I'm writing a game with two processes. One for rendering with OpenGL. The other is for Collision detection. This is so I can use more than a single core.

However I can't use any pygame surfaces without the display open. So I can't use bitmasks to do pixel perfect collision or any other collision for that matter.

I've tried to simply open another window just to see if I can the Surfaces to work but I can't open a second pygame window without getting an OpenGL function error.

You can open two non-OpenGL windows with pygame in two separate processes but I'm using OpenGL.

I figured there might be somewhere I can insert a pointer to the display to get the surfaces to stop saying `Dead Display`. Some kind of SDL variable I can manipulate in the second process to say "its not Dead its here". Or some other way to use the pixel perfect collision.

I'm open to pixel perfect alternatives that don't use pygame.

Comment: You are using multiprocessing, not threading? You might be able to, but It sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: its not. I can only get 40 shapes on the screen but if I dedicate a single core to rendering I get 200. I am using threading for the socket connections udp and tcp so that steals more from the main thread as well. I'm aiming minimun to play is dual core 2.0's I have a quad 3.5 and just running on a single 3.5 is still more than most people. Dual processes make it much more feasible.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with 200, rendering and collision same thread, same cpu. This test cycles through without the quadtree, then turns it on.

Then move the blocking code (network) to another thread.

Quote from running the example:

> Found peak. Preformance for this computer will not be any better then it is now.
> Would **normally have 359400 collision** checks,
> but this quadtree **reduces it to roughly 241** collision checks

The [original is pygame.org](http://www.pygame.org/project-Quadtree+test-1691-.html) But it needs a minor edit: http://pastebin.com/U371LaLy

[image]

Comment: I thank you a lot for an easy implementation of a quad tree. I hope I can use it. That solves the overhead for too many collisions I may be able to go from 40 to like 100-140 buuuut. If you rotate a sprite(not circle) the bit mask must be regenerated since you cannot rotate the bit mask alone. I limited this to a max of 10 times a second or if the rotation is greater than 20 degrees to keep accuracy. If I didn't do either of those I would have abandoned this 2 months ago. The pixel perfect masks much be regenerated if the shape is not a circle and it rotates.

Comment: You didn't read it. that's before the Quad is enabled. When it does, then **I get 50fps using less than 20% of my cpu**.  This doesn't even use numpy or other optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use pymunk. The python port of Chipmunk.

I did a silly experiment with it little over a year ago when I first started programming. It was pretty easy. I just totally forgot about it.

I couldn't get pybox2d to work in any python version.